# Toggling 'always on top' on a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I was wonder how I would go about making a JMenuItem that would allow a user to toggle the 'always on top' feature of a GUI I'm working on.  I know that I can just use `setAlwaysOnTop(...)` but I'd like to be able to change it mid-program.

I found something before but can't seem to locate it now, it used Ancestors or something like that, any ideas?

Comment: without code demonstraded your issue only :-) don't mix AWT Components and Swing JComponents

Comment: Your question is unclear. 'setAlwaysOnTop()' belongs to Window, so it is irrelevant for JMenuItem. What would you really want to do? I mean from the user/product manager perspective?

Comment: I want to be able to toggle the ability for the window to always be on top within the program.  If the user selects 'always on top' from a JMenuItem it will change the window's capabilities to have to program always on top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Add a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` titled something like `Always On Top` to a `JMenu`.
- When it is activated, call `window.setAlwaysOnTop(alwaysOnTopCheck.isSelected())`